# What are the best cursor (mouse) tracking applications for web sites?

Tags: javascript, statistics, tracking, mouse-cursor

What are the best cursor (mouse) tracking Javascript applications for web sites? To be stored in a database...

Comment: What's going to be stored in the database?

Comment: the movements of the cursor (the coordinates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that there is a pre-packaged general solution to this problem one-click away.

I would recommend picking a good Javascript framework (my personal favorite is [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), but [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is nice too).  Both of these libraries provide nicer ways of handling mouse events in a cross-browser compatible manner.

My advice:
Keep a queue of mouse events that you constantly push to a server via AJAX calls.  The server-side script that answers the AJAX request can push the data into a database of your choosing.

Take a look at this nice MooTools library for handling advanced mouse gestures to get a good feel of how you might accomplish the mouse movement recording: [Moousture](http://neofreeman.freepgs.com/Moousture/).

**Edit:**
After a little more Googling I also came across a [MooTools Flashlight Effect](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-flashlight) which does almost exactly what you want.  Instead of updating the position of the flashlight based on mouse movement, you would store the coordinates in a queue that gets pushed to a server later.